# How to access a Python global variable from C?

Tags: python, c

I have some global variables in a Python script. Some functions in that script call into C - is it possible to set one of those variables while in C and if so, how?

I appreciate that this isn't a very nice design in the first place, but I need to make a small change to existing code, I don't want to embark on major refactoring of existing scripts.

Comment: I think what you meant by global variable is only the `__main__` module's global variable. Actually each imported python module has its own global variables.
Builtin function [globals](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#globals)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I'm not a python guru, but I found this question interesting so I googled around. [This](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2007-September/427041.html) was the first hit on "python embedding API" - does it help?

> If the attributes belong to the global
>   scope of a module, then you can  use
>   "PyImport_AddModule" to get a handle
>   to the module object. For  example, if
>   you wanted to get the value of an
>   integer in the **main**  module named
>   "foobar", you would do the following:
>
> ```
> PyObject *m = PyImport_AddModule("__main__");
> PyObject *v = PyObject_GetAttrString(m,"foobar");
>
> int foobar = PyInt_AsLong(v);
>
> Py_DECREF(v);
> ```

Comment: 'This' link is broken- anybody have a fixed link?

Comment: Fixed it - Odd that they would rearrange the list archives like that, but googling for the quoted text found the message easily enough. :-)

Comment: Aaand its broken again

Answer (score 6):

For anyone coming here from Google, here's the direct method:

```
PyObject* PyEval_GetGlobals()
```

https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/reflection.html

https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/reflection.html

The return value is accessed as a dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Are you willing to modify the API a *little bit*?

- You can make the C function return the new value for the global, and then call it like this:

  `my_global = my_c_func(...)`
- If you're using [Robin](http://robin.python-hosting.com/) or the Python C API directly, you can pass the globals dictionary as an additional parameter and modify it
- If your global is always in the same module, Sherm's solution looks great

Answer (score -1):

I recommend using [`pyrex`](http://www.cosc.canterbury.ac.nz/greg.ewing/python/Pyrex/) to make an extension module you can store the values in in python, and cdef a bunch of functions which can be called from C to return the values there.

Otherwise, much depends on the type of values you're trying to transmit.