# Is it possible to get the PyObject reference from the name of an existing variable?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-c-api, pyobject

Is there a way to get object reference of an existing object,
in an embedded Python code?

In other words:
If an object called 'obj' already exist (created by a script),
and I need to "convert" it to a PyObject* reference, is there a function like: PyObject *getObjectReference(char *name) ?

EDIT:
As a way of example,
let's say I import some module in one part of the code, by using

```
PyRun_SimpleString("var = 1");
```

(Or as well it could be an external script defining the same variable)

Now, in another point of the code I want to get that variable. I'm looking for something like

```
PyObject *varPy = PyObject_GetGlobalObject("var");
```

"[reading a global variable of python in c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24732753/reading-a-global-variable-of-python-in-c)" partially answer my question by implicitly saying that it is not possible to retrieve a global defined variable without having a reference to the module that created it. Is this correct?

Comment: Could you add some more code showing what you're trying to do?

Comment: In response to your edit: if you know the name of the module the variable is in you can import it to get reference to the module (there's no problem with importing a module that is already imported).

Comment: Plus, if you look up the documentation for `PyRun_SimpleString` it tells you the module it's run in is `__main__`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions DavidW.
The variable is not made by any module, but by the main script.
I thought it could be retrievable from the __main__, but in the other question ("reading a global variable...") the guy says it didn't work for him (maybe because its variable was defined within a script?).
I will give it a try!

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks again.
I will write a full answer to my question for further reference.

Answer (score 1):

Assembling the info gathered from DavidW (thanks for you help), by the [reading a global variable of python in c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24732753/reading-a-global-variable-of-python-in-c) and a few tests I made.

To get the reference to an already loaded module, use:

```
PyImport_AddModule("module_name");
```

In order to get the reference to a globally defined variable, import the main module and get the reference by name:

```
PyObject *mainModule = PyImport_AddModule("__main__");
PyObject *var = PyObject_GetAttrString(mainModule, "var_name");
```

If the variable is defined within a different module/script, then it will be visible only in that module (not globally).
So you will have to change "**main**" with the name of that specific module.